# Motivation (and explanation) behind this function's definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, spheres, surface-integrals

Let $\mathcal S^2$ denote the unit sphere, i.e $\mathcal S^2=\{(x,y,z)\vert x^2+y^2+z^2=1  \}$ and consider a function $f \in C(\mathcal S^2)$. We set

$\begin{equation} 
g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int \limits_{\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}} f(x,y,z)\;ds\quad (*)
\end{equation}$

Our professor said the other day: **"The motivation behind $(*)$ is that in each slice of the sphere the function $f$ remains the same, hence it makes sense to average."**

I did not quite get this statement.

1. Since we're talking about average, shouldn't the denominator $2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}$ be equal to $\int \limits_{\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}} 1\;ds\;$? To me, it seems that the term $2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is of the form $2\pi \;r(x)$ where $r(x)=1-x^2$ is the radius of the disk $\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}$. But this if I 'm not mistaken stands for the perimeter of the disk (not for the area= $\int \limits_{\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}} 1\;ds\;$). How does then the denominator appear?
2. Why does the function remain the same on each slice of the sphere? What does this mean and how it is possible?

I hope my question is clear. I'm having a really hard time understanding this statement. Any help will be much appreciated.

***UPDATE:*** I think I might (almost) found the answers I needed.

1. After the comment of Ted Shifrin, I think that $\int \limits_{\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}} 1\;ds\;$ is indeed equal to $2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}$ since line integrals estimate in general the length of the curve and in this particular case the perimeter of the circle.
2. I think that what the professor was saying is that in each of these circles $\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}$ the function $f(x,\cdot,\cdot)$ remains constant. Thus it makes sense to take the average among all these constants.

Is my reasoning correct? I would be really glad if someone could verify this or explain instead what I'm missing here.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The $dS$ notation is wrong. This is in fact an integral over a curve (circle), not over a surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok you're right. However, the small $ds$ as a general notation for line integrals should be fine. But since this integral is a line integral then $\int \limits_{\{y^2+z^2=1-x^2\}} 1\;ds\;$ estimates indeed the perimeter of the circle, right?

Comment: Did your professor really say that "$f$ remains the same in each slice" or did he refer to $g$ instead? Because there is no reason for $f$ to remain constant on slices, but the constructed $g$ does.

Comment: @Didier Well, I can't put my hand in the fire for that. I might wrote it down in my notes in a wrong way. But $f$ as a function only of the $x-$coordinate, doesn't remain constant in each slice? Are we saying the same thing or not?

Comment: In general, $f$, being a function on the sphere, cannot be considered as a function of the coordinate $x$ alone (e.g $f(x,y,z) = x+y+z$). It may happen that $f(x,y,z)$ only depends on $x$ but it is quite rare. Averaging on each slice creates something that indeed only depends on the slice, so in your construction $g$ does not depend on $y,z$ but only on $x$. Note that in the particular case that $f$ does not depend on $y,z$, then indeed, $g$ and $f$ are the same function

Comment: @Didier Thank you very much for the clarification. One last question though: if we were assuming that $f$ is also invariant under rotation around the $x_1-$axis, then could "$f$ remains the same in each slice" make sense here? I mean, can one say then that on each such slice , $f$ is constant in terms of the $x_1$ coordinate?